# Do a command if option selected =

Tags: html-select, selected

This is the HTML code

```html
<option value="0" name="cv">Choose View</option>
<option value="1"name="profile">Profile</option>
<option value="2"name="privateserver">Private Server</option>
<option value="3">Group</option>
```

and this is the PHP code
create.php:

```php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['profile'])) {
        echo "profile";
    }
}
```

I don't know what to do please help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we need a form.
So Here we add a form.

> Html code

```
<form name="choose">
<option value="0" name="cv">ChooseView</option>
<option value="1"name="profile">Profile</option>
<option value="2"name="privateserver">Private Server</option>
<option value="3">Group</option>
<button type="submit">Done</button>
</form>
```

> Php code

```
$chosen = $_POST['choose'];
case $chosen{
case '1':
//1 is the value of option
//so if profile been chosen
//and do something

break;
case '2':
//do again 
//and again the 1,2,3,4 is the value of chosen option in HTML form
break;

}
```